# How to only lowercase quoted string in VIM

Tags: regex, shell, vim, lowercase

Say I have a file with the following content:

```
Apple 'BANANA' ORANGE 'PEACH'
```

What is the regex to convert all quoted uppercase to lowercase?

The expected output file should look like:

```
Apple 'banana' ORANGE 'peach'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
:%s/'\w\+'/\=tolower(submatch(0))/g
```

`'\w\+'` match any word that is inside quotes. and replace it with the lowercase version of the match. `\=` tells substitute to evaluate the expression `tolower(submatch(0))` where `tolower()` switches the string found in `submatch(0)` (the whole match) to lower case.

---

You can also use the `\L` atom to turn the string after it to lower case and `\0` is the same as `submatch(0)`

```
:%s/'\w\+'/\L\0/g
```

Take a look at `:h s/\L`